# Filtering in dynamic pattern from a file using Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, pattern-matching, filtering

I have a filtering in(include) and filtering out(exclude) criteria requirement, where I have below two files.

MAIN FILE
CountryCode|RegionCode|StateCode|FilterFlag
USA|NAM|NY|IN 
USA|NAM|NJ|IN
USA|MIDWEST|MI|IN
UK|EMEA|GB|OUT

Lookup File
CountryCode|RegionCode|StateCode|FilterFlag
USA|NAM|ANY|IN
USA|ANY|MI|OUT

Use Case:

1. In Lookup File, When FilterFlag has "IN", RegionCode and StateCode
   has "ANY", it should include all states and regions.
2. In Lookup File,    When FilterFlag has "IN", Any of the Region Code
       and Statecode has    "ANY", it should include all states or regions
       respectively.

Main File will never have "ANY", it will come with real values and should consider lookup data to filter in/out.

Comment: Not sure what your question is?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !myString.contains( "ANY" ) )
{
  Add/Store string
}
```

Check the string you're getting from the file contains "Any", if so, store it else do nothing.

Comment: Thanks, but my main file will never have "ANY" in it, my main file will have the values in it like, NY, NJ, FL, OR etc. Basically I want to change the main file data by looking at the look up file where I don't have a key, hence am using concatenate of all strings to compare both. Whenever there is ANY in lookup, by main file concatenate string should be ANY as I have explained in the example, that will return to a boolean true or false which will resolve my problem, Any help appreciated.

Comment: When I read line by line from input file, I am preparing a keypair(USA|NAM|NJ|IN) similar pattern to the below lookup file so as to compare all 4 columns of Input and Lookup, but I want to exclude the criteria whenever there is "ANY" in it. -- Can you clarify this please.

Comment: Zyn, Basically I dont have a primary key to lookup here. Hence am concatenating all required columns and comparing it with Main and passing by boolean true or false, true moves to then next logic and false ones rejects. But the tricky part is my lookup file can have a "ANY" value which means "include everything" there I dont want to compare and match both string, I want to ignore that particular value or change the main file string to "ANY". Also, "ANY" can come in RegionCode and StateCode Both

Comment: Sameer, can you give a larger representation in your original post of your main and look-up files. Could you then indicate through examples what you wish to happen?

Comment: I have edited the question to explain it with examples, hope it makes it clear now.